# Decision making algorithm (caret)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cart, caret

I would like to know if the caret package has decision-making algorithms other than the decision tree. I know the decision tree algorithm is intuitive and easy to explain, however, the decision tree algorithm has limitations in terms of accuracy and/or performance.

In my case, I need an output to explain the decision in a clinical context.

Thanks if anyone can help me with this topic.

Comment: The answer is yes.  See https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html

Comment: I thank you for your answer which is more general. I know this document. I need something more specific.

Comment: I'm happy to be more specific.  Maybe you could edit your question.  What information do you need that you are not finding in the `caret` documentation?